# How to allow tab on a custom control in HTML/Javascript (Aurelia)

Tags: javascript, html, custom-controls, aurelia, tab-ordering

I have created a custom control in Aurelia which is just a visual made up of divs (no actual input controls). When I tab through my form I would like to call a function to do stuff when the tab lands on my custom control, but it does not land on it as it is not an input. How do I get the tab to land on my custom control?

This will also apply for Angular and HTML in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish for a user to tab onto something, you should at first look into using other elements than `div`'s for said element (maybe a button?).

However, if you do need to use a `div` you can add `tabindex="0"` to it:

```
<div class="custom-control" tabindex="0"></div>
```

More info on the `tabindex` attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)